# Add space and keep elements on the right side

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have these 2 children elements and I want them on the right side(I have that working just fine), but now **I want to add more space between them** and having a hard time to get that to work. Can someone tell me what I'm missing, please? thanks

```css
section {
 background: yellow;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
 <section>
   <button>Cancel</button>
   <button>Confirm</button>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gap property can help you

```
    section {
        background: yellow;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        gap: 5px;
    }
```

dont create more containers if you can avoid this. This is my principle

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a default class to your buttons, or set a new class to your elements, and specify (for example) a margin that will be applied.

consider the following example:

```css
section {
 background: yellow;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
.elementContainer{
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <section>
  <div class='elementContainer'>
   <Button variant="secondary">Cancel</Button>
  </div>
  <div class='elementContainer'>
   <Button variant="primary">Confirm</Button>
  </div>
</section>
```

This will add a `5px` margin around each item with the `element` class.
you may change this style according to your needs.

Comment: I don't want to add a default class to these children elements because they will be added dynamically. I won't have control over those 2 children elements

Comment: Are they going to be all `Button` elements? or they can be anything? do you have control to have a container `div` around any element that will be added? if so, then style the container `div` and it should get you the same result.

Comment: If you added more information, I will modify my suggested answer.

Comment: Yes most of the time these children elements will be buttons but it's not guarantee. The parent container could be a "section" or "div" element

Comment: Can you control the added elements to have a container div around each one of them?

Comment: yes, I can control that. As long as it'd just one container for all of them. Kind of what I already have in place right now

Comment: I've modified my answer. let me know if this is what could solve your problem.

Comment: not really, I only have control over a single container, not a container for every child element

Comment: Then I guess you can use the `gap` property as per @Andrew's suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome! :) I'm going to remove this answer since it's not needed :)

Comment: I voted it up for your help and support

Answer (score 0):

You can use **column-gap**

So try this:

HTML:

```
<section>
   <Button variant="secondary">Cancel</Button>
   <Button variant="primary">Confirm</Button>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
 background: yellow;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 column-gap: 10px;
}
```